# Achieving following layout with Twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to achieve following layout with help of twitter bootstrap (12 columns):

[image: Layout]

At the moment I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">1</div>
    <div class="span6">2</div>
    <div class="span6">3</div>
    <div class="span6">4</div>
    <!-- etc.. -->
</div>
```

I was assuming that it will work, but for some reason it doesn't (all layout is just messed up) Is there a fix that need's to be applied in order for this to work? Or is it not achievable with bootstrap?

Comment: Do you want something like pinterest with 12 columns? (I didn't see 12 columns at first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- etc.. -->
</div>
```

?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? I believe that there is something wrong with it

Comment: you have a row with two cells, each cells has two rows

Answer (score 2):

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6"></div>
            <div class="span6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6"></div>
            <div class="span6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

if you want space between the rows you can add margin top or bottom for class "row"